# Remove true values from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following javascript array:

```
var foo = [false,false,true,false,true];
```

What I want is to remove 'true' values and keep false like this:

```
[false,false,false]
```

I have tried this:

```
console.log(foo.map(function(i){if(i==false)return i;}));
```

but what i get is :

```
[ false, false, undefined, false, undefined ]
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Try [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Surprisingly hard to find a dupe target for this (I'm **sure** there is one), probably because it's so basic. Most questions I can find are about arrays of objects and such.

Comment: The only difference between this and the linked dupe target (which was not trivial to find) is the condition for filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var foo = [false,false,true,false,true];
var filteredAry = foo.filter(function(e) { return e !== true })

console.log(filteredAry)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter), not [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var foo = [false,false,true,false,true];
console.log(foo.filter(function(i){ return i !== true; }));
```

That does what your question asks: Specifically filters out `true` values. Obviously, you can adjust the filter condition as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` property

```
var foo = [false, false, true, false, true];
var newArray = foo.filter(function(item) {
  return item === false;
});
console.log(newArray)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/hajgdqax/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with [ramdajs](http://ramdajs.com/)

```
var foo = [false,false,true,false,true, undefined, 0];
var isFalsy = R.filter(R.not);
isFalsy(foo);

//result: [false, false, false, undefined, 0]
```